# How can set Image Button height bigger than RelativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm beginner in android and want to design a simple footer to my application for that purpose write this xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#125688"
    android:gravity="center">
    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="45dp"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/left"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:foregroundGravity="right"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

every thing is ok but i want image button a little bigger show than relative layout box or footer,for more exmplain i want image button height bigger than layout,how can i solve that?thanks.

I want this output please click that:
[my Output](https://ibb.co/mgrVLv)

Comment: show some images or sketch what you want

Comment: @PratikVyas thanks my friend to pay attention to my problem,i cant post image ,please wait to find other server to show that

Comment: @PratikVyas please review my post my friend,upload image in my Output link

Comment: I will show you some code in few time span

Comment: @PratikVyas thanks to help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do like this,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary">


    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/profile__iv"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:layout_marginTop="-50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_circle"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

drawable/bg_circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="oval">

    <size
        android:width="60dp"
        android:height="60dp"/>
    <solid android:color="@color/White"/>

</shape>
```

Comment: thanks my freind but i dont want show red area,please click this link to see my purpose :https://ibb.co/iSACYF

Comment: you can remove parent Relative layout background color. I gave just to show difference

Comment: That's work,please wait finish that and accept your answer,thanks for pay attention to my problem my friend

Answer (score 0):

Not Possible.Because Imagebutton is child of Relative Layout. But Use set both are equal size.

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/footer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:background="#125688"
android:gravity="center">
<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/left"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:foregroundGravity="right"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Or Using this

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#B0BEC5"
tools:context="com.example.raj.jazzflurry.MainActivity">
<ImageButton
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_camera"
android:id="@+id/image"/>
<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:background="@color/cardview_dark_background"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:text="Hai"
    android:textAlignment="center"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```